# Sprite resolutions, aspect ratios, scaling and units to pixels for 2D Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, game-physics, screen-resolution

I'm about to create 2D Game, which will have world space equal to screen width and height, nothing more, viewed by one camera, on both sides(left and right) there will be 2 characters, one NPC and one character controlled by player, things will be happening in the middle, both characters will move only vertically and the things will go horizontally.

What I'm concern is how I'm gonna move the character and the things when there is multiple resolutions and how this Pixel to units translate to screen resolutions, so if i move my character standing at bottom for example 100 units it will go to the top, and it will be the same on other resolutions.

So my questions are:

- How and when to load SD, HD, etc. sprites?
- How to scale sprites so they much aspect ratios and different resolutions
- How to set pixels to units so my physics is the same on all resolutions

My targets are mobiles and tablets for now

Only thing I understand is the camera orthographic size which i set dynamically with this formula:

`orthographicSize = screen height / pixel per units / 2`